# MongoDB nearSphere only returns 100 results?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

Why a $nearsphere query always returns 100 results?

```
 db.mytable.find({"geo":{"$nearSphere":[41.393552,2.171344999999974],"$maxDistance":0.007}}).limit(500).count() -->>> 100 results
```

No matter about the value of $maxdistance, my table has more than 30.000 records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-739

Comment: Is there any other solution to perform this?

Comment: A workaround is discussed here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/mongomapper/MfRDh2vtCFg

Answer (score 0):

I think the asynchronous code is hitting the db.close(); before the .each loop finished, for some reason everyone is getting only 100 results, so here is a workaround.

```
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb';


  MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {

       var i=0;

       var collection = db.collection('documents');

       collection.find().each(function(err, docs) {

         if (docs != null){

            console.log(docs);
            console.log(i);

            i++;

            if( i >= docs.length ){
              db.close();
            }

          }


  });


});
```